# LocationClient removeLocationUpdates() before or after disconnect()

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location

When I get the requested location from the `LocationClient.onLocationChanged()`, is it better to

1. call `disconnect()` and then in `onDisconnected()` to call `removeLocationUpdates()` or to
2. call `removeLocationUpdates()` and `disconnect()` subsequently

?

Comment: quick look at decompiled source of GPS shows that disconnect() removes all listeners, so after disconnect() there is no need to call removeLocationUpdates()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if it removes listeners, Google still advices to remove all listeners before disconnecting.

Answering the question, though, LocationClient throws an error if you call removeLocationUpdates after disconnect(). So it's not so much where you should call it, but where you can call it!

Comment: can you point me to a reference where is this Google advice documented?

Comment: Sure, google example code here: http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html